# Adding attributes to textbox at runtime from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add attributes text a textbox at runtime as shown in the example below. The code below works, but the attributes only take effect after a full postback and I'm doing partial postbacks.

txtSKU1 is inside of an update panel which updates other textboxes, as seen in the  `DisplaySKUInfo` and `ClearSKUInfo` functions. That works great - but the attributes I am trying to add only work after a full postback - is there a way to reload the control without doing a full?

```
    protected void txtSKU1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sql.OpenConnection())
        {
            SKUInformation sku = sql.GetSKUInformation(txtSKU1.Text);

            if (sku.IsValid)
            {
                DisplaySKUInfo(sku.SKU, txtComp1, txtCost1, txtDescription1, txtMargin1);

                txtSKU1.Attributes.Remove("class");
                txtSKU1.Attributes.Remove("data-toggle");
                txtSKU1.Attributes.Remove("data-placement");
            }
            else
            {
                ClearSKUInfo(txtComp1, txtCost1, txtDescription1, txtMargin1);

                // These only work after a full postback
                txtSKU1.Attributes.Add("class", "popover-dismiss");
                txtSKU1.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "popover");
                txtSKU1.Attributes.Add("data-placement", "top");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using AJAX call?

Comment: Other than ignorance, no :) This is my first asp.net project that I was thrown into at work. The C# behind the scenes is easy - but the web portion is all new to me.

Comment: Can you please provide your ASP markup (part with update panel and text boxes)? Because I've created sample that you described and everything works fine.

Comment: Sure - here it is: http://pastebin.com/Bn3NVcYr

Answer (score 1):

I see few options here:

1. Move txtSKU1 to UpdatePanel and it will be automatically updated.
2. Use [ScriptManager.RegisterDataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb359752(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
3. Use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to register js that will set these attributes for you.

Comment: Still nothing. Using number 1 I thought for sure that would work. What makes it weird is I added the code to remove the attributes if it's a valid SKU (updated OP) it works - but only after a full postback (which I am triggering by clicking a button that does nothing). So I do this: 1) Enter invalid sku 2) Press Tab 3) Hover over textbox, nothing happens. 4) Click button, page refreshes. 5) Hover over textbox, popup appears! 6) Put in valid sku 7) Hit tab 8) (Did not click button this time) Hover over textbox, no popup... that's how it's supposed to work, without the button clicking.